# Save div data into csv file on server via php

Tags: php, csv

I have orders list div,
I want to save this div data into csv file in server using php
see the following code (https://jsfiddle.net/qwynj4to/)

```
    <div id="items">
    <div id="item1">
      Coke
    </div>

   <div id="item2">
      Pepso
   </div>

   <div id="item3">
     sprite
   </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: @ashkufaraz he said csv not excel

Answer (score 0):

You can use dom parser php module. you can download it from here http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

This module parse/select element same as jquery. you can retrieve data using this parser and store it in one dimentional array or multi dimentional array (if have more than one column). 
After that you can save it on CSV file using fputcsv() function, refere http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: Actually you have to prepare code your self. I have given key hint for your requirement only.